# When someone is falling out of favor with someone else (Informal equivalent)

Tags: word-usage, word-request, idioms, expressions, phrases

I am intrigued to know how would you normally imply the following notion in everyday speech?

When you do something which makes people stop liking you or admiring you you might **fall out of favor with them** or **loose favor with them**. These expressions sound quite formal and not colloquial to me.
I was wondering how would you use instead.

**Example:**

> - Sam's going the wrong way. The way he treats Cathrin is not fare and respectful. Once, she told me secretly, she's looking for an excuse to fall out with him and dump him. Sam has definitely ....... as time.

PS. in the opposite situation, informally, we can say something like:

> - He is **scoring points** with Cathrin.

Does **loosing points** sound idiomatically natural here? I.e. would it be possible to say:

> Sam is **losing points** with Cathrin.

I no, then what would be the best variant to imply that notion in modern everyday English?

Comment: Depending how informal you want to be - he has given her the s--ts, or he has p--sed her off. Teed her off might be a little more acceptable in polite society.

Comment: I need the most common way to say that informally, but still a polite way @Peter.